Do we want the cognitive-dissonance tag?
Do we want the cognitive-dissonance tag, if so, should it be synonymous with a broader tag?

It is fairly specific. That said, I've been thinking for a little while that there might be a few topics in social psychology deserving of their own tag. I.e., the idea would be to add the social-psychology tag as well as a topic tag. Basically, I'm thinking of typical chapter headings in a introductory social psych text book. So for instance:
We do have tags for

attitudes
love
emotions

We don't have tags for

conflict:
self, self-concept
aggression
person-perception
prejudice, stereotype, discrimination
conformity
helping, prosocial-behaviour
group-dynamics, teams
relationships, friendship

So I guess broadly this raises the issue of when we want to go to that next level of specificity in addition to the parent discipline.

should we make a general post, so people can write suggestions separately as answers and we can vote on each? I am hoping we will continue and that we will have a need for these types of tags
